# Why the js code works in a web page but fails in GreaseMonkey?

Tags: javascript, dom, greasemonkey

I created a hidden frame as follows:

```
var oHiddenFrame = null;
if(oHiddenFrame == null){
oHiddenFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
oHiddenFrame.name = "hiddenFrame";
oHiddenFrame.id = "hiddenFrame";
oHiddenFrame.style.height = "0px";
oHiddenFrame.style.width = "0px";
oHiddenFrame.style.position = "absolute";
oHiddenFrame.style.visbility = "hidden";
document.body.appendChild(oHiddenFrame);
}
```

then listener:

```
var fnLocation = function(){
frames["hiddenFrame"].location.href = "http://meckmeck.cn";
}

var oButton = document.getElementById("mb_submit");
oButton.addEventListener("click", fnLocation, false);
```

It works fine in a web page,but will report `frames.hiddenFrame is undefined` when written in **GreaseMonkey**

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666860/how-to-use-hidden-iframe-connect-to-the-server-in-greasemonky?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried,

```
document.getElementById('hiddenFrame').location.href = "http://meckmeck.cn";
```