# How to use hidden iframe connect to the server in GreaseMonky

Tags: javascript, dom, greasemonkey

First,I created a hidden frame like this:

```
var oHiddenFrame = null;
if(oHiddenFrame == null){
  oHiddenFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
  oHiddenFrame.name = "hiddenFrame";
  oHiddenFrame.id = "hiddenFrame";
  oHiddenFrame.style.height = "0px";
  oHiddenFrame.style.width = "0px";
  oHiddenFrame.style.position = "absolute";
  oHiddenFrame.style.visbility = "hidden";
  document.body.appendChild(oHiddenFrame);
}
```

Then,I add a event to the button like this:

```
var fnLocation = function(){
    frames["hiddenFrame"].location.href = "http://meckmeck.cn";
}

var oButton = document.getElementById("mb_submit");
oButton.addEventListener("click", fnLocation, false);
```

When I click the button,I got a error:

```
frames.hiddenFrame is undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as `document.frames`. The `name`-indexed frame array is `window.frames` (aka just `frames`).

0-iframes are so old-school, and these days mostly associated with malware-installing exploits (especially on Chinese pages). How about using an XMLHttpRequest instead?